# SQL or Python Most Efficient Way to Group Transaction History

Tags: python, sql, recursion, logging

I have a historical dataset where contracts can migrate into different systems and this can happen endlessly. I want to link these migrated contracts together.

I'm open to solving this using Pyspark or SQL (particularly redshift). SQL would be my preference.
I want to keep track of what was the first and last contract for every record (at this current point in time)

The dataset looks like this:

```
Old_contract, contract, migration_date
a123, b123, 2018-01-01
b123, c123, 2018-06-01
c123, d123, 2018-07-01
d123, e123, 2018-08-01
x123, y123, 2018-01-01
y123, z123, 2018-03-01
z123, y123, 2018-11-01
```

The output I would be looking for is:
Note how the second example results in y123 as z123 was changed back to y123

```
Old_contract, contract, migration_date, first_contract, last_contract
a123, b123, 2018-01-01, a123, e123
b123, c123, 2018-06-01, a123, e123
c123, d123, 2018-07-01, a123, e123
d123, e123, 2018-08-01, a123, e123
x123, y123, 2018-01-01, x123, y123
y123, z123, 2018-03-01, x123, y123
z123, y123, 2018-11-01, x123, y123
```

Comment: This requires a recursive CTE in SQL, which Redshift does not support.  So, stick with a Python solution.

Comment: Hey @shecode would appreciate an answer tick (or a comment if the answer doesn't cover what you need-- happy to change direction if I've missed your point.)

Comment: @Nick thanks for your response - i will review your answer ASAP. Thanks for putting in the effort to help

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that all a contract's history (its "contract trail", I've called it) occurs together, in a continuous series of rows. Two adjacent rows are grouped by the `contract` from the first matching the `old_contract` from the second. The contract trail is broken as soon as two adjacent rows are not linked in this way.

It's written as a class in case you want to do something more sophisticated later.

Note the line `if not self.grouped(row, self):` passes the contract trail built so far as a parameter to the grouping function. This means you can include a new row on the basis of any row or rows already in the group. Down the track, you might need to group non-continuous rows by using multiple `contract_trail` objects, perhaps using time in some way to end a group.

The code is reasonably efficient (you mentioned efficiency, but did not give any indication as to the size of the problem) and processes 100,000 rows/sec on my Windows 10 i5 laptop.

```
import csv


class ContractTrail:
    def __init__(self, writer, grouped):
        self.writer = writer
        self.trail = []
        self.grouped = grouped

    def add(self, row):
        if not self.grouped(row, self):
            self.flush()
        self.trail.append(row)

    def flush(self):
        rows = self.rewrite_transactions()
        if rows:
            self.writer.writerows(rows)
        self.trail = []

    def rewrite_transactions(self):
        if self.trail:
            first_contract = self.trail[0]["old_contract"]
            last_contract = self.trail[-1]["contract"]
            for transaction in self.trail:
                transaction["first_contract"] = first_contract
                transaction["last_contract"] = last_contract
        return self.trail

    def flush_to_csv(self, writer):
        rows = self.rewrite_transactions()
        if rows:
            writer.writerows(rows)


def link_to_previous_row(current_row, contract_trail):
    if contract_trail.trail:
        return current_row["old_contract"] == contract_trail.trail[-1]["contract"]
    # empty trail implies just started-- include current row in the group
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('trans.csv') as infile:
        with open('trans_out.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as outfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
            write_fieldnames = reader.fieldnames + ['first_contract', 'last_contract']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=write_fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            contract_trail = ContractTrail(grouped=link_to_previous_row, writer=writer)
            for row in reader:
                contract_trail.add(row)
            contract_trail.flush()
```

```
>>> python transaction_history.py

trans_out.csv:
old_contract,contract,migration_date,first_contract,last_contract
a123,b123,2018-01-01,a123,e123
b123,c123,2018-06-01,a123,e123
c123,d123,2018-07-01,a123,e123
d123,e123,2018-08-01,a123,e123
x123,y123,2018-01-01,x123,y123
y123,z123,2018-03-01,x123,y123
z123,y123,2018-11-01,x123,y123
```